# Apache Flink not able to start in cluster mode

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, apache-flink, amazon-emr

I tried installing Flink on Amazon EMR with 1 master & 2 core nodes..In flink-conf.yaml file,I set **jobmanager.rpc.address=EMR-MASTERDNS** & **taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=2** ...I then added the 2 Public IPs of core nodes in **slaves** file..I did all the same activities for the core nodes...but when I started the Flink cluster by `./bin/start-cluster.sh` & then I opened the Flink Dashboard,it said **taskmanagers=0,taskslots=0** ...I tried executing Flink java program,it threwed the error : `org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Not enough free slots available to run the job. You can decrease the operator parallelism or increase the number of slots per TaskManager in the configuration. Task to schedule: < Attempt #0 Resources available to scheduler: Number of instances=0, total number of slots=0, available slots=0` ...What is the proper configuration required to start Flink on Cluster i.e. in distributed mode ??

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Not enough free slots available to run the job. You can decrease the operator parallelism or increase the number of slots per TaskManager in the configuration. Task to schedule: < Attempt #0 (Source: Custom Source -> Timestamps/Watermarks (1/1)) @ (unassigned) - [SCHEDULED] > with groupID < 60c4962c2d8cb115a0c27d3115c71640 > in sharing group < SlotSharingGroup [] >. Resources available to scheduler: Number of instances=0, total number of slots=0, available slots=0

Comment: And the logs of the task managers?

Comment: I don`t see them in Flink-1.0.2/log location...Where do I get the logs of Task managers ??